# Dapper exception - Get<T> only supports en entity with a [Key] property, but [key] is defined

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, dapper-contrib

If the BO is marked as having a key with [key], why does dapper through an error?

```
[Table("tblWebReadyToWorkQualifications")]
public class TeacherQualificationBO
{
    [Key]
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }

    public string ReadyToWorkGuid { get; set; }

    public int QualificationID { get; set; }

}
```

Call to dapper that throws the exception

```
      public IEnumerable<TeacherQualificationBO> GetTeacherQualifications(int TeacherID)
      {
        using (var connection = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            return connection.Get<IEnumerable<TeacherQualificationBO>>(TeacherID);
        }
      }
```

The table `tblWebReadyToWorkQualifications` has a primary key on `TeacherID`.

> Error: 
>   at Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.SqlMapperExtensions.Get[T](IDbConnection connection, Object id, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout) in d:\egna projekt\dapper-dot-net\Dapper.Contrib\SqlMapperExtensions.cs:line 128\r\n

Comment: What is the error being thrown? stacktrace?

Comment: It should be noted that `Get()` is intended to get a single record, not a collection. `IEnumerable<T>` isn't considered valid. You will likely have to write your own query for this.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is probably trying to tell you that the generic type `IEnumerable<TeacherQualificationBO>` does not have a [Key] attribute, which is true. Only the type `TeacherQualificationBO` does.

change

```
return connection.Get<IEnumerable<TeacherQualificationBO>>(TeacherID);
```

to

```
return connection.Get<TeacherQualificationBO>(TeacherID);
```

You also need to change the return type of your function to `TeacherQualificationBO` to reflect this. You state that `TeacherID` is a primary key (thus unique), so `TeacherID` will only ever correspond to a single record. Thus it makes sense not to return a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone. In my case I was using the wrong namespace. Instead of *Dapper.Contrib.Extensions* Visual Studio had added *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations* which also has a *Key* attribute.